# Boolean algebra; what does <-> mean?

Tags: boolean-algebra

Expression :$$(p\rightarrow q)\leftrightarrow(\neg q\rightarrow \neg p)$$
What does the symbol $\leftrightarrow$ mean ? Please explain by drawing the truth table for this expression and also with other examples if possible. **I'm in a desperate situation so I'd really appreciate a quick response !**

Comment: Do you mean $\leftrightarrow$? This means bidirectional the sam as $\leftarrow$ and $\rightarrow$ toghether.

Answer (score 7):

Symbol $\leftrightarrow$ or $\iff$ denote usually the equivalence, commonly known also as "NXOR", "if and only if" or "iff" for short (see also [its Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if)). More precisely $p \leftrightarrow q$ is equal to $$(p \to q) \land (q \to p)$$ or $$(p \land q) \lor (\neg p \land \neg q),$$ and the truth table is:
$$
\begin{array}{cc|c}
p & q & p \leftrightarrow q \\\hline
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}
$$

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 0):

The expression $A\iff B$ means *if and only if*.

For $\iff$, we get the following truth table
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|}
& B\text{ is true}& B\text{ is false}\\\hline
A\text{ is true} & \text{true} & \text{false}\\\hline
A\text{ is false} & \text{false} & \text{true}\\\hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: Super ! Thanks a tonne

Answer (score 0):

$$A\leftrightarrow B$$ is the same as

$$(A\rightarrow B) \land (B\rightarrow A)$$

Answer (score 0):

All the answers above are great, and should help you. I will show you how I would do the full truth table for the logical statement: $$(p \Rightarrow q)\Longleftrightarrow(\neg q \Rightarrow \neg p)$$

\begin{array}{cc|c|c|c|c}
p & q & \neg q & \neg p & \neg q \Rightarrow \neg p & p \Rightarrow q\\\hline
T & T & F & F & T & T\\
T & F & T & F & F & F\\
F & T & F & T & T & T\\
F & F & T & T & T & T
\end{array}